# Deploy an application to a Wildfly server using Powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line, deployment, wildfly

Given a Wildfly application server running on Windows Server 2012 R2 I can invoke the deployment of a WAR like this:

```
C:\wildfly\bin\jboss-cli.bat --connect --command="deploy myapp.war"
```

How can I invoke the same command from a Powershell script? I have troubles with the quotes for the `command` parameter.

Comment: Just an FYI in WildFly 9+ there is a `jboss-cli.ps1` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this:

```
cmd.exe /C 'C:\wildfly\bin\jboss-cli.bat --connect --command="deploy myapp.war"'
```

Comment: Another way I solved this was to escape the quotation marks with the ` character. This way it is possible to expand any variables in the string.

Comment: I think from PS v3 onwards another solution is to use --% in the argument line in order to ignore the special characters: http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens